# Saving file with a specific name in Documents directory is failing in iPhone

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am using following code to save a file in iPhone Documents directory

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *mediaFile = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[message getMediaName]];
NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", mediaFile, IMAGE_EXTENSION]];
NSError *error = nil;
[data writeToFile:filePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
```

A sample of the filePath is

> /Users/Umar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8B419461-4E18-4E2F-923D-01092CA2263C/data/Containers/Data/Application/AD869525-92F9-4C5A-8FCE-CF67F05F8CEA/Documents/Users/Umar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8B419461-4E18-4E2F-923D-01092CA2263C/data/Containers/Data/Application/AD869525-92F9-4C5A-8FCE-CF67F05F8CEA/Documents/32286_1_44f74dc9d027d53bfa3e0bde9a28bf49.jpg

The path upto documents do exist and I have checked via Finder. Not sure Why i am getting error `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The folder “32286_1_44f74dc9d027d53bfa3e0bde9a28bf49.jpg” doesn’t exist."`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in this two lines

```
NSString *mediaFile = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[message getMediaName]];
NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", mediaFile, IMAGE_EXTENSION]];
```

Output of `mediaFile` is

`/Users/Umar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8B419461-4E18-4E2F-923D-01092CA2263C/data/Containers/Data/Application/AD869525-92F9-4C5A-8FCE-CF67F05F8CEA/Documents/32286_1_44f74dc9d027d53bfa3e0bde9a28bf49`

Output of `filePath` is combination of

`documentPath` + `mediaFile` + `Image Extension`

So problem is that document path exist two times, that's why compiler have problem in finding path and returning error.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: your welcome, it's ok, sometimes even happen with me :)